# How do you handle different KeyError in your code

Tags: python, exception, keyerror

Let say my dictionary can have 3 different key-value pairs. How do i handle different KeyError with if condition.

Let's say.

Dict1 = {'Key1' : 'Value1, 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3' }

Now if I try Dict1['Key4'], it will through me KeyError: 'Key4',

I want to handle it

```
except KeyError as error:
     if str(error) == 'Key4':
        print (Dict1['Key3']
     elif str(error) == 'Key5':
        print (Dict1['Key2']
     else:
        print (error)
```

It's not getting captured in if condition, it still goes in else block.

Comment: Use `in` instead of `==`

Comment: tried it, still doesn't work

Comment: Put it the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python KeyErrors are much longer than just the key used. You have to check if `"Key4"` is *in* the error, as opposed to checking if it is *equal* to the error:

```py
except KeyError as error:
     if 'Key4' in str(error):
        print (Dict1['Key3'])
     elif 'Key5' in str(error):
        print (Dict1['Key2'])
     else:
        print (error)
```

Comment: It didn't work, for testing I printed the str(error) it's exactly same as let say 'Key4' but still doesn't go in the if block

Comment: Oh ok so you are comparing the other way, got it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple approach:

```
dict1 = {'Key1' : 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3' }

key4 = dict1['Key4'] if 'Key4' in dict1 else dict1['Key3']
key5 = dict1['Key5'] if 'Key5' in dict1 else dict1['Key2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use `dict.get()` to give you a default value if the key doesn't exist:

```
dict1 = {'Key1' : 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3' }

print(dict1.get('Key4', dict1.get('Key3')))
# Value3

print(dict1.get('Key4', dict1.get('Key2')))
# Value2
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError)